AbortError: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request
I am working with Vue and have an issue as follows. The current component receives two props: isVisible and currentPdfPageForAi, which are used to change the video source in the component. Everything works well in all cases, except for one: If one video plays automatically from the beginning to the end, and then switches to the next video by changing the currentPdfPageForAi prop.
My Vue File:
<template>
    <div v-show="isVisible" class="ai-container cursor-pointer" @click="updateVisible()">
        <video :src="videoUrl" ref="video"></video>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import config from "./../../../env";
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            videoUrl: '',
        }
    },

    props: {
        isVisible: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        currentPdfPageForAi: {
            type: Number,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        updateVisible: function () {
            this.$emit('update-visible', '');
        },

        getVideo: function () {
            this.videoUrl = `${config.MINIO_SERVER}/${config.MINIO_BUCKET_NAME}/${config.MINIO_AI_VIDEO_FOLDER}/${this.currentPdfPageForAi}.mp4`;
        },

        videoTimingController: function () {
            let video = this.$refs.video;

            if (this.isVisible) {
                this.getVideo();
                video.load();
                var playPromise = video.play();

                if (playPromise !== undefined) {
                    playPromise.then(_ => {
                        video.currentTime = 0;
                        video.play();
                    })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('error while playing video: ', error);
                        });
                }
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }
        },
    },

    created() {
        this.getVideo();
    },

    mounted() {
        //hi
    },

    watch: {
        currentPdfPageForAi(newVal) {
            this.getVideo();
            this.videoTimingController();
        },

        isVisible(newVal) {
            this.videoTimingController();
        },
    },
};
</script>


I think the error will occur when the video finishes playing.
